# List files where a pattern is not matched!

Tags: java, regex

I use a product called Crash Plan Pro and it uses regular expressions for matching its exclude files. I need a expression to list the files in a directory where a pattern is not matched, case insensitive. What I have to date that works on a global scale is

```
(?i)^((?!(/*(-cd|-cw|-cm).spi|.*/)$).)*$
```

But unfortunately this is not specific to the directory I need to target.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tell us what you do want to match and what you dont. Provide plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard and clumsy to say "but not ..." using regexes. Maybe you can switch the list from "include" to "exclude"?

Answer (score 0):

Does it support negative lookahead?  If so, that's an easier way of saying "not."  If it is using Java regular expressions, it definitely supports negative lookahead.  If it is using another language, it might or might not.